# Connman wireless access point - notification on failed connection

Tags: dbus, wpa-supplicant, connman

We are currently setting up a Wireless access-point in our device using connman, with out own connman agent (implemented in C++) providing passphrase and SSID. This works quite well. What I'm currently looking for however, is a way to get a notification to the agent when a connection attempt fails, for example when someone tries to connect using the wrong passphrase. Is is possible to do something like this via for instance DBus?

We have implemented and registered the ReportError method of the Agent-api, but it does not appear to get called when the connection attempt fails. Looking at the syslog I can see wpa_supplicant logging that a failed connection attempt was made, but nothing is forwarded to the agent.

Is it at all possible to do something along these lines? It does not necessarily have to be via the agent-api (though that's preferable), just any way to get a notification on failed connection attempt.